# I seem to be doing something wrong when using the Heroku CLI Installer for MacOS

Tags: heroku

After downloading the installer I follow the installation steps and everything appears to be fine. Then I open terminal and enter **heroku** into the command line then press return.

Everything online says that I should be prompted to login with my Heroku credentials, but instead I'm sent to the **Help topics** page.

I'm just starting a coding bootcamp so a lot of this stuff is new to me. If anyone has experienced this or knows of a fix, I'd greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: does `heroku auth:login` prompt for a login?

Comment: I'm never prompted for a login. It sends me straight to Help Topics.